# Retrieving access token using FB.login

Tags: facebook, oauth, access-token

I've rechecked my code many times but i am unable to display the access token on the page using the FB.login function. Everything works fine, FB.ui gets me the access token in the return url and the status checks are all fine but the access token doesn't show up in the tokendiv when the user logs in through FB.login. Please tell me what i'm doing wrong !

```
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js">
</script>
<script>
FB.init({ 
appId:'113381182103752', cookie:true, 
status:true, xfbml:true 
});
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
if(response.status=="connected")
{
document.getElementById("status").innerHTML="User is connected";
}
else if(response.status=="notConnected")
{
FB.ui({
client_id: '113381182103752',
method: 'oauth',
redirect_uri: 'http://127.0.0.1:8888/test2.php',
response_type: 'token'
});
document.getElementById("status").innerHTML="User is logged in but not connected";
}
else if(response.status=="unknown")
{
FB.login(function(response) {
if(response.authResponse)
{
var token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
document.getElementById("tokendiv").innerHTML=token;
}
});
document.getElementById("status").innerHTML="User is logged out";
}
});
</script>
<div id="tokendiv"></div>
<div id="status"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try writing

```
FB.init({ 
appId:'113381182103752', cookie:true, 
status:true, xfbml:true, oauth:true 
});
```

instead of

```
FB.init({ 
appId:'113381182103752', cookie:true, 
status:true, xfbml:true 
});
```

If you don't do that you won't get the response.authResponse in the login function, but the old response.session which should no longer be valid.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I knew about that but i would've never realized what was missing.

Comment: But now there's another problem. FB.ui doesn't show a dialog box when oauth:true in FB.init. It does when i remove oauth:true from FB.init. Know why that's happening?

Comment: This is documentation on the oauth dialog http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/ The best way to find errors in your code is to use firebug or some other browser developer tool. This will let you see when a javascript error occurs. If you are using IE you can press F12 and get the developer tool out. Then go to the "Console" tab and see if there is an error.

Comment: I use firefox. I have pinpointed the issue, when 'oauth:true' the code in 'else if(response.status=="notConnected")' does not run. The error console does not show any errors just the regular warnings.

Comment: But now i've found that theres a seperate developer tool for inspecting in firefox called the scratchpad and that is showing an error. I'll see to it and update. Thanks

Comment: Got firebug too. But issue solved: the response.status object had some other value than 'connected', 'notConnected' and 'unknown'. So i just put an else condition with FB.ui in it and now it is showing up.

Comment: Oh and i found why thats happening too. 'notConnected' is replaced with 'not_authorized' in Oauth 2.0.